# Can Xcode Document-based app be set to always open in a new tab

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, document-based

I have an macOS xcode swiftui document-based app.  I can see that if I, "view->show tab bar" in the app, I get multiple tabs for free.  However, if I do a "file open ...", it creates a new window.  Now I eventually found that holding down option when selecting the file will open it in a new tab of an existing window.  Does anyone know if it is possible to configure a document-based app to always open in a new tab rather than a new window each time?

Comment: Hint: `makeWindowControllers`

Comment: Have you tried the tabbing settings of the window?

Comment: I can enable tabs via "Show Tab Bar", which persists between runs.  However, each time that I open a new file it is opened into its own tabbed window.  I am trying to organise it such that when I open a file it is added to a new tab of the current window.  I have found the addTabbedWindow function, which I could use in makeWindowsControllers (where the document window is instantiated).  I am currently stuck digging around trying to work out how to find and identify the parent window to use as the arg to addTabbedWindow.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `tabbingMode` property of the window to `preferred`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `window.tabbingMode` to `preferred` in `makeWindowControllers()`.

```
override func makeWindowControllers() {
    // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
    let contentView = ContentView()

    // Create the window and set the content view.
    let window = NSWindow(
        contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
        styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
        backing: .buffered, defer: false)
    window.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
    window.center()
    window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
    
    window.tabbingMode = .preferred // open new document in tab
    
    let windowController = NSWindowController(window: window)
    self.addWindowController(windowController)
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, even simpler.  Easy when you know the magic 8-).  However, I learnt a lot other useful stuff along the way.

Answer (score 1):

OK, for anyone who ends up here.  Thanks to the hint from El Tomato, I have achieved (mostly) what I wanted.  Key steps are:

1. Get the window in the application that has a tabGroup property that is not nil
2. Having got that, then use the addTabbedWindow function to add your window to the tabGroup
3. If the application has no window with a populated tabGroup property, then you have no tabs, so once you have a new window, invoke the toggleTabBar function to show the tabBar.  The subsequent calls to makeViewControllers will find the window that contains the tabs.

Code from the makeWindowControllers for me was...

```
let tabsWindow = NSApplication.shared.windows.filter({$0.tabGroup != nil}).first
let window = NSWindow(
  contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
  styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
  backing: .buffered, defer: false)
window.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
window.center()
window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
if tabsWindow != nil {tabsWindow!.addTabbedWindow(window, ordered: .below)}
else { window.toggleTabBar(self) }
```